# Can't use certain jquery functions on hover effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set a function that displays a hidden ficaption once the figure it is located in is hovered over. I have been able to test that the hover function is working by setting an alert message, but I just can't seem to change the figcaption's css in any capacity.  This is an example of the html for each figure:

```
<figure class="grid-block">
  <img src="img/image.jpg">
  <figcaption class="to-reveal"></figcaption>
</figure>
```

And my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".grid-block").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("figcaption").css("display","block!important");
  });
});
```

How can I properly get the figcaption to display when it's figure is hovered over?

Comment: Can you share any relevant CSS?

Comment: Remove the `!important`

Comment: @j08691 that's one of the last thing's I'd expect to cause the problem but removing !important did indeed fix it. Thanks very much.

Comment: [Here's the relevant bug report](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173) as to why `!important` won't work with `css()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

**First:**: If there is no text in your `figcaption`, what do you really expect to see on `hover`?

**Second**: You will need to use the two possible handlers of `.hover()` method in order to show it when the mouse is over the `figure` and to hide it when the mouse leaves.

So here is it working:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".grid-block").hover(
    function(){
      $(this).find("figcaption").css("display","block");
    },
    function(){
      $(this).find("figcaption").css("display","none");
    });
});
```

```css
figcaption{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<figure class="grid-block">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports">
  <figcaption class="to-reveal">
    There must be some text in your figcaption to see it!
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Louys- I didn't include text for the figcaption in my example because it wasn't totally relevant, but I indeed am placing text in the ficaptions.